# Pytorch model: how to find out framework version?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a trained Pytorch model. When I try to use it, I get dozens of SourceChangeWarnings, e.g.: SourceChangeWarning: source code of class 'torchvision.models.segmentation.deeplabv3.DeepLabV3' has changed. you can retrieve the original source code by accessing the object's source attribute or set `torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True` and use the patch tool to revert the changes.
warnings.warn(msg, SourceChangeWarning)

How can I find out which Pytorch version I need to avoid these warnings? Thank you.